# Just bought an ROG Strix B450-F motherboard. Do I need to upgrade my old Corsair TX750W PSU or is it compatible?

Tags: motherboard

Wasn't able to figure out if I need to buy a new power supply for this motherboard, the PSU I have is not listed on the pcpartpicker compatibility page https://pcpartpicker.com/products/power-supply/?compatible_with=XQgzK8 (This may be because it isn't sold any more)

The PSU looks like it has the right connection but I really don't want to just hook up a potentially incompatible power supply, is anyone able to confirm that this combo would be ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ROG Strix B450-F](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/ROG-STRIX-B450-F-GAMING/) is an ATX mainboard, so the relevant information can be found on [WikiPedia's article about ATX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#ATX_power_supply_revisions). The ATX connectors are designed in a way that you cannot connect them in a wrong way (unless they are broken in some way = defective).

The article about [ATX power supplies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_(computer)#Connectors) states that the ATX standard connectors are backwards compatible:

> ATX12V 4-pin power connector (also called the P4 power connector). A second connector that goes to the motherboard (in addition to the 24-pin ATX motherboard connector) to supply dedicated power for the processor. 4+4-pin For the purpose of backwards compatibility, some connectors designed for high-end motherboards and processors, more power is required, therefore EPS12V has an 8-pin connector.

and

> 6+2-pin For the purpose of backwards compatibility, some connectors designed for use with high end PCI Express graphics cards feature this kind of pin configuration. It allows either a six-pin card or an eight-pin card to be connected by using two separate connection modules wired into the same sheath: one with six pins and another with two pins. Each PCI Express 8-pin connector can output a maximum of 150 W.

So summarized: if your power supply's connectors do fit, the PSU can be used safely.
And if your power supply didn't provide enough power, the computer would simply turn off.